# Pug: how do I include mixins across all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a file `includes/mixins.pug` that has some mixins. I also have a main layout file `layouts/default.pug` that I am `extend`-ing. How can I include those mixins in my layout file so that I don't have to write `include includes/mixins` on every page?

For example, this is what I have to do for each additional pug file. In this case: `new_page.pug`

```
extends layouts/default
include includes/mixins

block content
  +my_mixin('Hello World')
```

`layouts/default.pug`

```
doctype html
html(lang=$localeName)
  block vars
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0") 

    block styles
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.min.css")
  body
    block content
```

How do I include the mixins in `layouts/default.pug`? I had trouble finding a solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `include` the mixins higher up in the view inheritance hierarchy, for example at the top of `layouts/default.pug`. The mixins will then be available in the scope of all children views.

```
include includes/mixins

doctype html
html(lang=$localeName)
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!